# How to use __builtin_return_address() recursively?

Tags: gcc, recursion, stack, return

I was trying to play with the function `__builtin_return_address` in GCC to learn some basic concepts about runtime data structure.

My test code is this

```
#include <stdio.h>

void a(int i)
{
    if (i>0) {
        printf("The return address is %p\n",  __builtin_return_address(0) );
        a(--i);
    }
    else
        return;
}
int main ()
{
    a(10);
    return 0;
}
```

And the output is

```
The return address is 0x4005ee
The return address is 0x4005db
The return address is 0x4005db
The return address is 0x4005db
The return address is 0x4005db
...
```

So my question is, why are the return addresses of those recursively called functions the same like they are all returning to the top-level caller? Shouldn't they be something like "recursive direct caller" as well?

Comment: Because while each function call's frame is ever further lower on the stack, each instance of the function call is executing the same _code_, and the return address is the address of the instruction in the _code_ of the function `a()` immediately after the `call` instruction to `a()` itself. To see steadily-decreasing addresses, print the address of a local variable in the function's frame, like `&i`.

Comment: That has the look of tail recursion optimisation. Try compiling the code with all optimisations off - e.g. Using `-O0`, which may prevent the optimisation from taking place, thus yielding what you expect.

Comment: @Petesh, it doesn't look like any optimization. I tried -O0 before as I suspected it, too. But apparently it didn't change anything...

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist, sorry but I am still feeling confused. I can roughly understand what you explained, but if I am not mistaken, the return address should point to the exact location where the "next instruction" is located so it should be a "returning address chain" or similar. Or else after a(0) call completes it would then jump back to the top-level caller a(10), which doesn't sound quite like the expected execution order... Thanks.

Comment: @Peng That's partially correct. It is the next instruction after the call returns, _but it's the very same code being executed by each of the function instances, so it's the very same instruction being pointed to!_ What distinguishes the 10 function instances is **not** the return address, identical for each of them, but the _stack pointer/frame base pointer_, and maybe not even that if tail recursion occurs. Try `__builtin_frame_address(0)`, and make sure optimizations are _off_.

Comment: @Peng I'll amend that statement by saying that in the case of the first call to `a()` the return address points within the code for `main()`.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist, thanks for your patient explanation. I understand that each recursion should execute the same code, but it doesn't sound (to me) that the same code would result in the same return address to be stored. Assuming the a(10),...a(0) all lead to the same return address, after a(0) exists, how does the instruction at this unique return address determine what to do next? To continue a(10) or something else? For example, in this lecture note, page 6, it actually says the same thing I was expecting: a stack-like return address sequence.

Comment: Sorry it was too long so I have to paste the lecture note here:
http://www.cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall04/V22.0201-003/ia32_chap_03.pdf

and I just double checked the assembly code GCC generates to make sure the functions are called recursively, and the stack is indeed growing.

Comment: @Peng do you notice the `<- ESP` comments? ESP is the stack pointer register in the IA32 architecture, and it is _it_ that is growing. "Location" in the slides is not **the** return address; It is the location **of** the return address on the stack. The return address pointers found _at_ both `Location 000FFFF8` and `Location 000FFFF4` in slide 6 will be **identical**, since they are both "the point past the call of `f` in `f`" in the machine code for function `f`.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist, okay I think I understand know. To exaggerate I manually called a(10) twice in main. And as you said, the "return address" is in fact the next instruction immediately following the "call" instruction in the a() section of objdump. No matter how and when a() is called. As your crystal clear explanation in the last post, I now know that I was confusing *the* return address instruction and the address where it actually points to, like confusing pointer with its value pointing to. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: @Peng Just prior to the `ret` from the innermost call to `f`, ESP == 0x000FFFF4, and therefore points to `Location 000FFFF4`, containing the address of the instruction past the call of `f` in `f`; Let's say this address is 0x0400183E. Just after that `ret`, ESP == 0x000FFFF8, and therefore points to `Location 000FFFF8`, containing the address of the instruction past the call of `f` in `f`: 0x0400183E. In both cases, they point to the same place _in_ the code. It _is_ the true return address; The machine is executing the same code at the same address for both calls to `f`.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist Thanks again for your explanation. :) I guess I was in fact looking for a mean to "dereference" the return address or in other words, find the "return address" on the stack. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

```
f5 f4 f3 f2 f1 a(5) -->  f5
f5 f4 f3 f2 f1 a(5) a(4) -->  f3
f5 f4 f3 f2 f1 a(5) a(4) a(3) -->  f1
f5 f4 f3 f2 f1 a(5) a(4) a(3) a(2) -->  a(4)
f5 f4 f3 f2 f1 a(5) a(4) a(3) a(2) a(1) -->  a(2)
```

Don't change index during recursion !

```
f5 f4 f3 f2 f1 a(5) -->  f5
f5 f4 f3 f2 f1 a(5) a(5) -->  f4
```

stop on `ret_add(i) == ret_add(0)`

Comment: Avoid unseful recursion, prefers here a for while/loop ! `while(i>0) {  printf("The return address is %p\n", __builtin_return_address(i--));   }`